# How to access the last list in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So let's say I have the following list.

```
[1,2,[3,4,5,6,[7,8,[9]]]]
```

Is there an easy way to access the list [9] without doing a function?

Comment: For that value, `x[-1][-1][-1]`, but I imagine you mean in the general case of nested lists...

Comment: `list[-1][-1][-1]`!?

Comment: 1) Flatten the list; 2) `flatten(list)[-1]` for the last element

Comment: note that brtt requested the last list, not the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop:

```
L  = [1,2,[3,4,5,6,[7,8,[9]]]]

lastList = L
while isinstance(lastList[-1],list): 
    lastList = lastList[-1]

print(lastList)
[9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are functions with another syntax, so this answer might not be what you really want, but

```
>>> x = [1,2,[3,4,5,6,[7,8,[9]]]]
>>> z = lambda x: z(x[-1]) if len(x) > 1 else x
>>> z(x)
[9]
```

Comment: This is not a general solution. It only works in this narrow case.

Comment: @dawg But I guess it's the flaw of the question. The question was not clear enough how general the solution is expected. To me it is fairly general (in terms of the depth of nests), given the question. It is the question what is to be blamed.

Comment: Agreed. That is why I originally closed it but then saw that there was a pony in there...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
li=[1,2,[3,4,5,6,[7,8,[9,10]]]]
```

You can use a recursive function to find the last list:

```
def flatten(L):
  last_list=[]
  for item in L:
    try:
      last_list.append(item)
      yield from flatten(item)
    except TypeError:
      yield last_list
```

Then just exhaust the generator and the last one is the last list:

```
>>> for l in flatten(li): pass
>>> l
[9,10]
>>>
```